# Trying to delete pointers triggers breakpoints

Tags: c++, class, pointers, delete-operator

The purpose of the program that I'm working on is creating a class to "improve" the default integer array data type by simulating a dynamic array of pointers.    I keep running into errors when trying to delete pointers and arrays of pointers where it says "Windows has triggered a breakpoint in project4.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in project4.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while project4.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information."

```
class Array
{
private:
    int length;
int* data;
public:
    Array();
    Array(const Array &cpy);
    ~Array();
    bool addint(int toadd);
    bool deletelast();
    int getlength();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Array &n);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Array &n);

Array::Array()
{
    length = -1;    
    data = NULL;
}

Array::Array(const Array &cpy)
{  
    length = cpy.length;                //value of length is copied

    if (length < 0)
        data = NULL;
    else
    {
        data = new int [length];

        for (int i=0; i<=length; i++)
            data[i] = cpy.data[i];
    }

}    

Array::~Array()
{
    if (length != 0)
        delete [] data;
    else
        delete data;

    data = NULL;
}  

bool Array::addint(int toadd)
{   
    length ++;
    int* point = new int[length];

    for (int i=0; i < length; i++)
        point[i] = data[i];             

    point[length] = toadd;

    if (length != 0)    
        delete [] data; 

    data = point;

    point = NULL;

    return true;
}    

bool Array::deletelast()
{
    int* temppoint;
    if (length > 0)
        temppoint = new int [length-1]; 
    else
        temppoint = new int[0];

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)        
        temppoint[i] = data[i];

    if (length == 0)
        temppoint[0] = 0;

    length --;
    delete [] data; 
    data = temppoint;
    temppoint = NULL;

    return true;
}  

void menu(Array var)
{
    int selection=0,
        input;
    bool success;
    Array* arrcpy;
    while (selection != 3)
    {
        if (var.getlength() == -1)
        {
            cout << "What would you like to demonstrate?" << endl << "1) Add an integer " << endl
            << "2) Exit" << endl << "Enter your selection: ";
            cin >> selection;
            if (selection == 2)
                selection = 4;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << endl << "Now what would you like to demonstrate?" << endl << "1) Add an integer " << endl
            << "2) Delete the last entered integer" << endl << "3) Copy constructor" << endl << "4) Exit" << endl << "Enter your selection: ";
            cin >> selection;
        }

        if (selection==1)
        {
            cout << endl << "The length of the array before adding a new value is: " << var.getlength() + 1 << endl;
            cout << "Please enter the integer that you wish to add: ";
            cin >> input; 
            success = var.addint(input);
            if (success)
                cout << endl << "The data input was a success!" << endl << "The length of the array is now: " 
                << var.getlength() + 1 << endl << "The new value of the array is: " << var << endl;
            else
                cout << endl << "The input failed" << endl;
        }       
        if (selection == 2)
        {
            cout << endl << "The lenght of the array before the deletion is: " << var.getlength() + 1 << endl 
                << "and the value held in the array is: " << var << endl;
            success = var.deletelast();
            if (success)
                cout << endl << "The data deletion was a success!" << endl << "The length of the array is now: "
                << var.getlength() + 1 << endl << "The new value of the array is: " << var << endl;
            else
                cout << endl << "The deletion failed" << endl;
        }       
        if (selection == 3)
        {
                cout << endl << "The lenght of the array being copied is: " << var.getlength() + 1 << endl 
                << "and the value held in the array is: " << var << endl;
                arrcpy=new Array(var);
                cout << endl << "The length of the copied array is: " << arrcpy->getlength() +1 << endl
                << "and the value contained in the array is: " << *arrcpy;
                delete arrcpy;
        }
    }
}
```

This is all of the relevant source code that I have in terms of the issue that I'm having.  It's coming up that every instance of the `delete` operator and the `delete []` operator has resulted in this breakpoint error and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Edit: Rewrote the code to have the value of length default to 0 instead of -1 and everything works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int* point = new int[length];
```

Since your length starts at -1, the first call of this line would be to do `new int[0]`. Could be the problem.. If you insist on not fixing the semantics of `length`, you want `length+1` here

Unrelated point, you should look at how `std::vector` does it, instead of reallocating every addition, you should try overallocating and only reallocating if the space is filled.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input.  I rewrote it using the default length at 0 and it works perfectly now.  I still don't understand exactly WHY it does that, but either way I got it to work thanks to your input and I will take note of this in the future if I come across anything like this again.  But once again, thank you very much for your input.

Comment: @rob630 It doesnt work because you are confusing what `length` means. If there are 5 elements in your array, the length should be 5, but in your case it would be 4. It does wrong in addint function which always allocates 1 short, because it assumes length means length, which, in the case of default -1, it doesnt

Comment: Oh...  wow, of course.  That makes perfect sense.  I was thinking of it in terms of the elements, which an array[5] would be array[x] where x would be numbers 0-4...  That was a silly mistake.  Thanks again for the help and especially for helping me understand my error.  :D

Answer (score 2):

I believe the `for (int i=0; i<=length; i++)` in the copy constructor should contain `i<length` (less than, not less than or equal to).  That's one clear problem.

Also you're passing the bound in the `addint()` method.  The last element in an array is at index [length-1].

Comment: the value of length is defaulted to -1 and incremented each time a number is added to the "Array", so if I made it i<length, it wouldn't copy the value if the array size was 0, hence the <=

Comment: @user1907309 you are misusing the term length then. Length cannot be negative, and it should be `i<length` What you are using it as appears to be something like `previousIndex`

Comment: It was a requirement for the project that it be called length, just the way that I figured to do it would have it start at -1 and increment to the actual value each time the function was called.  The only time the value is -1, the value of the pointer is null.  Perhaps it's my inexperience speaking here, but I'm not quite sure why this would be causing this issue.

Comment: @user1907309 then you might want to clean up the confusion, if only to make such issues easier to spot. Think of it this way.. if your array has one item, whats its length?

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is an old thread and I'll admit I haven't read all the comment but on the topic of why it seems to work when lenght is changed to 0 I believe it could be due to a nullptr being given to an array being made of an invalid size and later, trying to delete such pointer would result in the breakpoint.